# Is there an equivalent of x-accel-redirect for serving pages instead of files?

Tags: headers, nginx

There is an [X-Accel](http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel) module in `nginx` that allows to serve files by returning the `X-Accel-Redirect` header to the `nginx` server. Is there a way to serve pages like this?

For example, I have a web service that uses `apache` behind `nginx` that can either process the request by itself, or have it redirected to some legacy service. What I want is to have that redirection happen seamlessly, so the user might think that it was the first service that handled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how I can achieve this. All I needed in my case was an error handler:

```
location @legacy {
  proxy_pass        http://upstream;
  proxy_set_header  Host  legacy.host;
  proxy_redirect    off;
}

error_page 404 =200 @legacy;
```

So in case the main upstream server returns the `404` error code, the request is proxied to the legacy host.